# Archive URL not found when trying to deploy using heroku buttons

Tags: heroku, deployment, oneclick

I am facing an error while trying to install an app using a heroku button (https://heroku.com/deploy?template="app_url").

[image]

This used to work all the time. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Where is the button you're trying to use?

Comment: Thanks. I think it is fixed now. I was trying to use the button on Hasura GraphQL engine docs: https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/getting-started/heroku-simple.html